# Generic error occured in GDI+ calling Image.Save

Tags: c#, winforms, callback, marshalling

The image is actually a byte array pumped from my native DLL (as Byte *).

I am converting it into an image as follows.

```
Img = new Bitmap(g_Width, g_Height, g_Width * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, ptr);
```

Note: The "Image" is in the global scope. "ptr" is an IntPtr(local scope).

I am trying to save this image from the BackgroundWorker method. When I do so, I get "A generic error occurred in GDI+" exception.

What is the I am missing?

**Edit:**

I am trying to save the image like

```
Img.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Also, I have tried to save the image as soon as I create the image. The file is saved successfully. I am able to display as well. But I am not able to save in from the worker.

**Edit 2:**
Globals:

```
BackgroundWorker Worker;
Image img = null;
```

The callback is as follows,

```
private unsafe void GrabFrame(Byte* InputBuff, ref Int32 lBufferLen) 
{
   Img = new Bitmap(g_Width, g_Height, g_Width * 3, 
         PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, (IntPtr)InputBuff);


   //Img.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);    // This works fine.

   Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);                              
   Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Img.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);  //This is were i get the exception
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Exception at Worker_DoWork: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Modified code:**

Globals:

```
BackgroundWorker Worker;
Image img = null; 
Byte[] g_Buffer;
Intptr ptr;
```

The callback is as follows,

```
private unsafe void GrabFrame(Byte* InputBuff, ref Int32 lBufferLen) 
{
   Img = new Bitmap(g_Width, g_Height, g_Width * 3, 
         PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, (IntPtr)InputBuff);


   g_Buffer = new byte[lBufferLen];
   Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)InputBuff, g_Buffer, 0, lBufferLen);

   //Img.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);    // This works fine.

   Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);                              
   Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(g_Buffer.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(g_Buffer, 0, ptr, g_Buffer.Length);

        Img = new Bitmap(g_Width, g_Height, g_Width * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, ptr);

        Img.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);  //still issue persists

        // Call unmanaged code
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Exception at Worker_DoWork: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Edit 4: Working Code**

Please find the modified code.,

In call back,

```
 Byte[] Buffer = new Byte[lBufferLen];
 Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)InputBuff, Buffer, 0, lBufferLen);

 Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
 Worker.DoWork += (obj, e) => Worker_DoWork(obj, e, Buffer);
 Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

And the worker,

```
void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e, Byte[] Buffer)
{
    try
    {
        Image Img = null;
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Buffer.Length);

        Marshal.Copy(Buffer, 0, ptr, Buffer.Length);

        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Img = new Bitmap(g_Width, g_Height, g_Width * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, ptr);
        }

        Img.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Exception at Worker_DoWork: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: We are missing the save command, including the path. Also: Does the image 'work', ie can you display it in eg a PictureBox?

Comment: @sam Please provide full code including worker and image retreival.

Comment: @sam `GrabFrame` is callback from unamanaged environment? If so, it's obvious your asynchronous worker fails to save data since they were probably already released. You need to copy data in `GrabFrame` into e.g. managed `byte[]` and then save it in worker.

Comment: @vasek I have modified the code as per your comment. Still, the issue persists. Please find the modified code in the question.

Comment: @sam don't make your `g_Buffer` global, create it locally in `GrabFrame` and then pass it into your worker as an argument. Also `ptr` and `img` do not have to be global.

Comment: @vasek I tried as you suggested. Still, I get the exception.

Comment: @sam Update your code please

Comment: @vasek the above code is working. thank you :)

Comment: @sam What was wrong then?

Comment: I had to allocate the memory for the Intptr.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you @Vasek. As suggested in the comment, I had to create a local buffer and pass it to the worker.

Please find the working code in the edited question.